# Conditional formatting with multiple rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is an example of my worksheet of 200 rows.

I want to compare each row individually with the benchmark value at the end. If the value < the benchmark on the row, then the value within the row will be coded as red. If the value > then the benchmark on the row, then all the values within that row will be code as green.

[image]

Comment: In `A1` enter the conditional format of `=A1>$D1` and copy the format across and down.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. What have you already tried?

Comment: You can create more than one conditional format rule. Select your data (A2:C5) and input the formula that DBC wrote above. Pick your format. Then repeat with another rule and change > to <= and select your other color.

Comment: Thanks DBC and Isolated. It seems working very well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:
Select the Range you want to format and go to **Home**- **Conditional Formattin**g- **New Rule**- **Use a formula to determine which cells to format** and enter the formulas and create the format:

Green: `=A2>$D2`

Red: `=A2<$D2`

[image]